# When Teaching R, how to avoid the possible confusion with the term ''variable''?

Tags: r, variables, communication, terminology

In the R official docs, the term ''variable'' is used to describe two distinct things:

1. The name we give to any type of object with the `<-`operator or with `assign`

   For instance, we could say that in `a <- data.frame(0)`, a is a variable, i.e. a symbol that links that particular dataframe to it.
2. A vector or a factor, belonging or not to a structure like a matrix or a dataframe, and containing units of data which, we assume, can take any of several or many values.

   In this case it's akin to the statistical version of the term, such as in ''random variable''.

So my question is the following:

*How do I help students understand the difference between programmatic and statistical usage of the term `variable` when teaching R?*

(thanks and credits to @Gregor who formulated it in a better way than I would.)

Comment: You really seem to want a discussion, which doesn't fit in with SO.  Your only question is answered in your post. Try r/rstats on Reddit. My opinion is: there is no problem. R is a statistical programming language, thus using the "statistics" definition of variable as well as the "programming" definition of variable is to be expected. (You also don't have a viable proposal for how we *should* refer to "programming" variables.) Even if some sort of quorum could be reached, any effort to discourage use would be largely ineffective, e.g., `stringsAsFactors` still defaults to `TRUE`.

Comment: Actually I wondered if other programmers (and especially people who need to teach programming) had found a way to avoid confusion between those two uses. But thanks for your input.

Comment: That's a decent question! I don't think it would necessarily be on topic here, but "How do I help students understand the difference between programmatic and statistical usage of the term *variable* when teaching R?" is a clear, focused question. And very different from the question asked. There isn't a `teaching` tag, which makes me think it would probably be considered off-topic here as well, but it's at least a real question.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase then!

Comment: Done. Although no teaching tag exists yet (and I don't have enough points to create a new tag) so I put communication instead.

Comment: I use the term "object" to refer to a named item in the workspace, and use "column" to refer to named matrix or dataframe columns. When I use "variable" I am generally referring to 'terms' in formula-expressions. Named nodes or branches in list-structures are a problem. I generally call them 'items' or 'leaves'

Comment: Interesting strategy, thanks for sharing this @BondedDust